# Saving API data to JSON file with NodeJS (or PHP)

Tags: javascript, php, json, node.js

Is there a way to save data from an API to a JSON file, with NodeJS using XMLHttpRequest?

The API data is supposed to be displayed on a website, but the API is increcibly slow, so to combat this I would save the data on the server and display the newest data on the website every 5 minutes.

The API is public, the link is http://lonobox.com/api/index.php?id=100002519 if that helps.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It should be possible.. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Read up on how to set up a cron job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey I do a similar thing with a node server that performs basic function on JSON data that I use at work. When it comes to saving the data I just POST it to the server.

But when it come to reading the data I use a XMLHttpRequest to do it, let me illustrate how it works which should give you a good start.

**POST file to server.**

```
function processFile(e) {
    var file = e.target.result,results;


    if (file && file.length) {
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "http://localhost:8080/",
          data: {
            'data': file
        }
        }).done(function(msg) {
            appendText("Data Saved: " + msg);
        });
    }
}
```

From here you can fetch the data with XMLHttpRequest like so...

```
function getFile(){
    var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    rawFile.open("GET", "filename.json", false);
    rawFile.onreadystatechange = function ()
    {
        if(rawFile.readyState === 4)
        {
            if(rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0)
            {
             var fileText = rawFile.responseText;
         }
     }
 }
 rawFile.send(null);
}
```

**Server Code**

```
app.post('/', function(req, res) {
    var fileLoc = __dirname.split("\\").length > 1 ? __dirname + "\\public\\filename.json" : __dirname + "/public/filename.json";
    fs.writeFile(fileLoc, req.body.data, function(err) {
        if (err) {
            res.send('Something when wrong: ' + err);
        } else {
            res.send('Saved!');
        }
    })
  });
```

Server side requires FS and I use Express for routing.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this. My goal is also to send a new request if the JSON file is changed, but without making more than 1 request to the API.


My current "matching data function" is not very good, it will keep making new requests till it gets an answer, it will end up making a lot of requests since it takes 30 seconds+ for the API to respond.

Comment: No worries let me know how you get along. Hmmm sounds like you could use a callback somewhere in your code if you're making too many requests. Can you clarify how your code works for me? 

- Request API for JSON (Takes ages?)
- Match against current saved JSON for differences?
- If changed save new JSON?